# simple sidebar bootstrap 2nd level menu

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using this template [Simple Sidebar](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/)

I want to add a second level menu like in this template [SB Admin 2](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/index.html)

I tried to use an accordion with bootstrap but it doesn't look good

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <ul class="sidebar-nav">
    <li class="sidebar-brand">
        <a href="#">
            Start Bootstrap
        </a>
    </li>
    <a href="#demo4" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" data-toggle="collapse" > Fist <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <div class="collapse" id="demo4">
        <a href="" class="list-group-item">Dashboard</a>
        <a href="" class="list-group-item">Shortcuts</a>
        <a href="" class="list-group-item">Overview</a>
        <a href="" class="list-group-item">Events</a>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it with jQuery :) ...set the 2nd menu to `display: none;` and call a function `.on('click')` that slides down the collapse

```
$('.link-with-submenu').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.collapse').slideDown();
});
```